# How to get the count of total no of rows and count of a particular value from a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has three column - An `Id`, a foreign key and `Status`. I need to find the no of active(value = 1) status in the table and the total rows in the table. How to do it in a single query.

Output of this query is Joined With another Table.

```
select FK, Count(1) as active_count, <missing> as total_count from table where status = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select 
    FK,
    count(1) total_count,
    sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) active_count
from table
--group by FK
```